# Could not determine artifacts for com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:18.0.0

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, google-vision, firebase-mlkit

I'm not able to build my project in Android Studio. I'm trying to use the google vision API for face detection and it worked fine so far, but I can't clean/ build my project because of this

This is my build error message

```
Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
Could not determine artifacts for com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:18.0.0
Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/android/gms/play-services-vision/18.0.0/play-services-vision-18.0.0.aar'.
Could not HEAD 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/android/gms/play-services-vision/18.0.0/play-services-vision-18.0.0.aar'.
Remote host closed connection during handshake
SSL peer shut down incorrectly
```

This my build.gradle file (app level)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.facedetect"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'
    implementation "com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0"
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:18.0.0'


    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation 'com.mindorks:paracamera:0.2.2'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Project level build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2'

    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com'}

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

buildscript {

    dependencies {
        // Add this line
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.0'
    }

}
```

When I remove the

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:18.0.0
```

The project build succeeds. Is something wrong with the way I'm adding the dependency?

Comment: Is your problem fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. Looks like I needed to invalidate caches and restart both android studio and my computer. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

I think you have problem with your dependency classpath. You created two buildscript dependencies. Instead, you can include one or more plugins (dependency) in same buildscript.

You can have root **build.gradle** as below:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Also, you don't have to write google maven url `maven { url 'https://maven.google.com'}` separately, since `google()` will do the same thing for you.